# How to enable the helper now in Lumen

Tags: php, lumen, php-carbon

I'm new to Lumen (version 7) and then i'm trying to use carbon as usual like in Laravel especially the helper **now** but I'm getting this error

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\now()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `\Carbon\Carbon::now()` are you looking for this? I am not sure why would a controller will be calling a function directly.

Comment: @Rafee Yes I found this solution, but can we not have a helper as in laravel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look for `function now` in the vendor of a Laravel app, you would find it's located in **src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php** and as Lumen aims to be lighter (and faster) than Laravel so it comes with fewer tools than Laravel, such file loaded for each request to provide functions shortcuts is the kind of small bottleneck that have been sacrificed.

You still can create your own helper in any global place:

```
function now($timezone = null)
{
    return Carbon::now($timezone);
}
```

It would be equivalent.

Else, calling `Carbon::now()` will make explicit that you get a `Carbon` instance. I would say it's not so bad to type it for each new instance you created.